# Download file Curl with url var

Tags: php, curl

I would like to download a file with Curl.
The problem is that the download link is not direct, for example:

```
http://localhost/download.php?id=13456
```

When I try to download the file with curl, it download the file download.php!

Here is my curl code:

```
        ###
        function DownloadTorrent($a) {
                    $save_to = $this->torrentfolder; // Set torrent folder for download
                    $filename = str_replace('.torrent', '.stf', basename($a));

                    $fp = fopen ($this->torrentfolder.strtolower($filename), 'w+');//This is the file where we save the information
                    $ch = curl_init($a);//Here is the file we are downloading
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // Important 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fp);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0); // None header
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1); // Binary trasfer 1
                    curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    fclose($fp); 
    }
```

Is there a way to download the file without knowing the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

> TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part
>   of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many
>   "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is
>   set).

So it will result into:

```
function DownloadTorrent($a) {
    $save_to = $this->torrentfolder; // Set torrent folder for download
    $filename = str_replace('.torrent', '.stf', basename($a));

    $fp = fopen ($this->torrentfolder.strtolower($filename), 'w+');//This is the file where we save the information
    $ch = curl_init($a);//Here is the file we are downloading
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // Important 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0); // None header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1); // Binary transfer 1
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the FOLLOWLOCATION option to true, e.g.:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Options are documented here:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 1):

Oooh !

CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION work perfect...

The problem is that I use **CURLOPT_URL** for fopen(), I simply change **CURLOPT_URL** whit **CURLOPT_FILE**

and it works very well! 
thank you for your help =)