# Download application/msword with cURL on localhost

Tags: php, curl, download, localhost

I have researched here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php and have enabled cURL, verified it is working correctly.

What is the best way to perform a file download (application/msword) using cURL on localhost (before moving to a hosting plan)?

A somewhat similar question exists here: [Download file Curl with url var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370138/download-file-curl-with-url-var)

The path to the file is known as $path, however, the URL is dynamic and is populated with the id of the file.

Path is populated like this:

```
$path = "./uploads/{$_SESSION['email']}/"; 

$path = $path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

Here is a look at the download link itself:

```
<a href='ppage.php?id={$row['uid']}'>Download</a>
```

I currently have the following, and cannot get any output or error messages:

```
                $fp = fopen ($path, 'w');
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                fclose($fp);
```

The file is a .doc and I can open it manually from its location.  Permissions of the dir, subdir and the file itself are temporarily 777. If you could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What trouble are you having?  It's hard to help you without knowing what's in `$path`.  Also, where are you setting your URL?  Finally, you are not downloading a text file.  Word Document !== text.

Comment: I am trying to see if I am missing a curl_setopt() somewhere in order to get some kind of result.  Currently cURL won't complain about anything being incorrect and the file won't download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is all of your code, then you are missing the part where you set a URL to download:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.something.com/somefile.doc');
```

Comment: Thanks, but my URL would be something more like this: http://localhost/download.php?id=13456    The URL is dynamic and depends on which file the user would like to download.

Comment: @V1GG3N, So plug the right URL then!  Also, why are you downloading from yourself?  Why not load the file directly?

Comment: Plugging in the right URL does nothing!  I have curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/path/to/my/downloadpage.php?id=261'); which is the URL to a specific test file. I can't even get an error message. What do you mean by load directly?

Comment: Try a proper URL with `http://` at the beginning, drop your extra semicolon before `)`, enable error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.  By load directly, I mean that from what you've said so far, there is no reason to use cURL at all.  Why go over HTTP if you're loading things from localhost?  Are you trying to capture the output from a script?

Comment: Error reporting is on, and for some reason my above comment got messed up, I have a proper URL beginning with http:// and there is no extra semicolon. I am attempting to use cURL as a workaround for a rogue header issue while trying to download using normal http headers and output buffering. I'm using this approach to test before moving to a hosting plan.